# Can't drawRect line

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, drawrect

I'm trying to connect lines at each tap the user makes. The dots where the user tapped are created, but the lines that connect them are not. It gives me the following error:

```
CGContextAddLineToPoint: no current point.
```

Can anyone tell me why? I checked SO and couldn't find anything relevant, as my stroke method is at the very end. Here is what I am trying:

```
  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        o = 0.5 / 1.0;
        sW = 5.0;
        r = 255.0/255.0;
        g = 59.0/255.0;
        b = 48.0/255.0;
        first = CGPointZero;
        second = CGPointZero;
        third = CGPointZero;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self setOpacity:o];
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(first, CGPointZero)) {
        first = [touch locationInView:self];
    }
    else if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(first, CGPointZero) && CGPointEqualToPoint(second, CGPointZero)) {
        second = [touch locationInView:self];
    }
    else if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(first, CGPointZero) && !(CGPointEqualToPoint(second, CGPointZero)) && CGPointEqualToPoint(third, CGPointZero)) {
        third = [touch locationInView:self];
    }
    else {
        first = CGPointZero;
        second = CGPointZero;
        third = CGPointZero;
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(first, CGPointZero) && CGPointEqualToPoint(second, CGPointZero)) {
        first = [touch locationInView:self];
    }
    else if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(first, CGPointZero) && !(CGPointEqualToPoint(second, CGPointZero)) && CGPointEqualToPoint(third, CGPointZero)) {
        second = [touch locationInView:self];
    }
    else {
        third = [touch locationInView:self];
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];


}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self drawBitmap];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [incrementalImage drawInRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, sW);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, o);
    NSLog(@"R:%f, G:%f, B:%f",r,g,b);

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(first, CGPointZero)) {
        CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(first.x, first.y, 20, 20);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y);
    }

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(second, CGPointZero)) {
        CGRect rectangle2 = CGRectMake(second.x, second.y, 20, 20);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle2);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle2);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, second.x, second.y);
    }

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(third, CGPointZero)) {
        CGRect rectangle3 = CGRectMake(third.x, third.y, 20, 20);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle3);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle3);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, third.x, third.y);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
}

- (void)drawBitmap {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    //CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 255.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0, 1.0/1.0);
    if (!incrementalImage) { // first draw;
        UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds]; // enclosing bitmap by a rectangle defined by another UIBezierPath object
        [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
        [rectpath fill]; // fill it
    }
    [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, sW);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), r, g, b, o);

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(first, CGPointZero)) {
        CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(first.x, first.y, 20, 20);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y);
    }

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(second, CGPointZero)) {
        CGRect rectangle2 = CGRectMake(second.x, second.y, 20, 20);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle2);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle2);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, second.x, second.y);
    }

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(third, CGPointZero)) {
        CGRect rectangle3 = CGRectMake(third.x, third.y, 20, 20);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle3);
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle3);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, third.x, third.y);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Also, the stroke color is always black. I nslog it and it states the correct color. What doesn't make sense about the no current point error, is the fact that I use that same parameter for creating circles at the tap and it works fine, the only thing that doesn't work is the line.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error message?

Comment: If you simply want to draw lines, UIBezierPaths might be easier to use. (and look better)

Comment: @Cutetare: I do simply want to draw lines, but I tried UIBezierPath and that didn't work either.

Comment: Try adding the line `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill); `
after your stroke path

Comment: @Cutetare: Nothing :(, I added all my code, does any of it help at all?

Comment: If you add a symbolic breakpoint for CGPostError, you should be able to know at least where the error is getting throwed

Answer (score 1):

Here you are calling for the third point, but it should be second.

```
if(!CGPointEqualToPoint(third, CGPointZero)){
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, second.x, second.y);
}

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle3);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle3);
```

Here you are calling for the third point again, but in the proper place

```
if(!CGPointEqualToPoint(third, CGPointZero)){
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, third.x, third.y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was an error, but not the cause of the error listed above.

Comment: np, just something i noticed.  unfortunately not sure about the error.